# Using Linux Shell to run a Client - Server for numbers of time

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm coded two programs, one is Server, the other is Client.

The purpose of these two programs is file transfer. First, the Server program will be started up, then the Client program. the client program will receive a file from server.

I want to run a test to see how much time will the transfer be for many file sizes. Each file size I will do about 10 times.

The code is ok. When I write two scripts like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$1
for((n=0;n<time;n++))
do
    ./server "3mb.MP3"
done

#!/bin/bash
time=$1
for((n=0;n<time;n++))
do
    ./client $n
done
```

And run the Server script first and then the client script. I realize that because of for loop, many instances of server are created and so the client. I just want one client and one server communicate with each other at a time. When the file transfer is over, we will create a new pair of client-server.

Is there any solution?

Thank you!

(I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.)

Comment: It isn't the script that is a problem, it's how you write the server/client code. Change the server program to either accept multiple clients simultaneously (assuming you didn't just copy/paste code), or ensure that each server is able to run independently from the other.

Comment: thank you, but in my test, one server communicate with one clien at a time. If one server accept multiple clients, the result is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a global `for` loop instead of loops for each client and server, if you need is one client-server per iteration. Something like --

```
time=$1
for((n=0;n<time;n++))
do
    ./server "3mb.MP3"
    ./client $n
done
```

To find the execution time of your script, you can use  `time ./x.sh` which will give you the execution time of the overall script...if you want execution time for each iteration, then you have find `start` and `end` times for each loop and subtract the later from the former.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it's as simple as

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$1
for((n=0;n<time;n++))
do
    ./server "3mb.MP3"
    ./client $n
done
```

You might need this if your server isn't forking internally:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$1
for((n=0;n<time;n++))
do
    ./server "3mb.MP3" &
    ./client $n
done
```

The ampersand causes the shell not to wait for the server process to finish.

(Thanks to Floris)

Comment: I suspect you need `&` after the server is started or you will wait until the server has finished before starting the client?

Comment: @Floris I assumed that the server was forking, but you are right if it isn't.